# Java generics static type inference

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

I do have an abstract class with an delegation interface defined:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass extends AsyncLoader {

public interface MyAbstractClassDelegate<M> {
    //The parameter in this method should be the concrete subtype of MyAbstractClass
    public M performThisCall(MyAbstractClass concreteSubclassOfAbstractClass);
}

private MyAbstractClassLoaderDelegate delegate;
    ...
}
```

The Problem is, I do not want the delegate parameter to be `MyAbstractClass`, instead it should be the concrete subclass. Why? Because the implementation of the delegate needs the concrete subclass for further handling and I don't want to cast it...

I know I could define an `Interface` in **each subclass**, but it'll look the same in every subclass  except for the parameter type

***EDIT***

Here is the perfect solution solving exactly what I wanted. Great thanks!

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {

public interface MyAbstractClassDelegate<M, Subtype extends MyAbstractClass> {
    public M myMethod(Subtype t);

}
```

}

Is this possible with **java 6** and if yes - how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be:

```
public final class Example<T extends Example<T>> {

    public interface Interface<M, Subtype extends Interface<M, Subtype>> {
        public M myMethod(Subtype t);

    }
}
```

You have no access to the generic from the outer class inside the interface (because the interface is static) so you have to declare it again.

If you use your interface you get something like this:

```
private static class Impl1 implements Interface<String, Impl1> {

  @Override
  public String myMethod(final Impl1 t) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

I don't know if it will help but here is my complete example:

```
public final class Example<M, T extends Example.Delegate<M, T>> {

  public interface Delegate<M, Subtype extends Delegate<M, Subtype>> {
    public M myMethod(Subtype t);
  }

  private T delegate;


    private static class Impl1 implements Delegate<String, Impl1> {

      @Override
      public String myMethod(final Impl1 t) {
        return null;
      }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Example<String, Impl1> example =  new Example<>();
    example.delegate = new Impl1();
    example.delegate.myMethod(example.delegate); //works but whout?
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, with Subtype its working, althoug Subtype extends MyAbstractClass was what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to give your abstract class a type parameter with the concrete subclass, similar to the way Java's `Enum` does it.

Something along the lines of this:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass<S extends MyAbstractClass<S>> extends AsyncLoader {

    public interface MyAbstractClassDelegate<M, S> {
        public M performThisCall(S concreteSubclassOfAbstractClass);
    }

...
```

Comment: I've tried this already, unfortunately the compiler says "MyAbstractClass.this cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: @Alexander there is no static context in samples and your question, so you are making mistake somewhere else.

Comment: @Alexander For what code does it give that error message?

Comment: @Smallhacker for the S within the interface

Comment: @Alexander Are you trying to declare a subclass with `class Abc extends MyAbstractClass<this>`? If so, no, that's not how it works. You would do `class Abc extends MyAbstractClass<Abc>`.

Comment: Oh right, my apologies. I forgot that inner interfaces become a static context. You would have to add the type parameter `S` to the interface's parameter list as well.